# Weight not showing in Admin Product

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, product-weight

Magento 2.3.4

Weight does not show for any products in admin.
The attribute exists and is part of the attribute set.

Database values seem to all be there for the attribute.

Can't understand why it doesn't show on admin.

Comment: What is the value for the attribute in the `apply_to` column in the `catalog_eav_attribute` table?

Comment: Awesome, this solved it, please enter this as answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `weight` attribute should be applicable to the product types below.

- simple
- virtual
- bundle
- configurable
- downloadable
- giftcard

If the attribute is not applicable for a specific product type the attribute won't show up.

In the `catalog_eav_attribute` table there is a column (`apply_to`) which determines to which product types the attribute can be applied. It's a comma separated string of product types, or `NULL` if the attribute is applicable to all product types.

Looking at the above list of product types the value for the `weight` attribute should be like this.

`simple,virtual,bundle,configurable,downloadable,giftcard`